# Vue 3 Instante Root Component with data after Promise

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I need to initialize a Vue 3 app with data (item object) returned from a Promise and access it from all components.
The fetched item should be passed to the app before anything else.

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import store from "../store";
import DetailPage from '../views/DetailPage.vue'

my_promise().then(fetched_item => {
  const app =  createApp(DetailPage)
  app.item = fetched_item // this doesn't works
  const vm = app.use(store).mount('#app')
})
```

**detailpage.vue**

```
<template>
  <navbar-component></navbar-component>
</template>

<script>
import NavBar from '@/components/detailpage/NavBar.vue'
export default {
  name: 'DetailPage',
  data(){
    return {
      item: {text: 'default'}
    }
  },
  components: {
    'navbar-component': NavBar
  }
}
</script>
```

but if I try to access `this.$root.item` from another nested components

```
mounted(){
  console.log("root", this.$root.item)
}
```

I get

```
Proxy {text: "default"}
```

instead of the fetched item passed at initialization

Comment: Is your app a SPA? If yes, you could add a condition in one of vue-router hooks (e.g. beforeRouteEnter) to fetch this data (if it already has not been fetched) and then store it in a state so that your other components can access it.

Comment: No it's a chrome extension (Content-scripts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createApp()` returns the [*application instance*](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/instance.html#creating-an-application-instance), but you need the [*root component*](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/instance.html#the-root-component) (i.e., the result of `app.mount()`), which allows accessing the component's data properties:

```js
const app = createApp(DetailPage)
const vm = app.use(store).mount('#app')
vm.item = fetched_item
```